# How to view last created file?

Tags: linux

I have uploaded a file to a Linux computer. I do not know its name. So how to view files through their last created date attribute ?

Comment: Use `find`, e.g. with `-ctime`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
ls -lat
```

will show a list of all files sorted by date. When listing with the -l flag using the -t flag sorts by date. If you only need the filename (for a script maybe) then try something like:

```
ls -lat | head -2 | tail -1 | awk '{print $9}'
```

This will list all files as before, get the first 2 rows (the first one will be something like 'total 260'), the get the last one (the one which shows the details of the file) and then get the 9th column which contains the filename.

Comment: `ls -1 -t | head -1` will also work to only return the last modified file.

Comment: In case if you want to save the latest file name as a variable: `LATEST=$(ls -lat | head -2 | tail -1 | awk '{print $9}')`

Comment: Thanks. If the name of the file contains a blank, it will be truncated. I used `ls -lat | head -2 | tail -1 | cut -f10- -d' '`

Answer (score 14):

```
find / -ctime -5
```

Will print the files created in the last five minutes. Increase the period one minute at a time to find your file.

Comment: This actually means 5 hours ago. `-cmin` seam the correct option to search up to five minutes ago.

Comment: for 5minutes please remove the `-` correct would be `find / -cmin 5`

Comment: From the man page: -ctime n File's status was last changed n*24 hours ago.  See the comments for -atime to understand how rounding affects the interpretation of file status change times. so -ctime -5 correspond to the last 5 days

Comment: Not `created` but `changed` - there's a distinction.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you know the folder where you'll be searching it, the most easy solution is:

```sh
ls -t | head -1
# use -A in case the file can start with a dot
ls -tA | head -1
```

- `ls -t` will sort by time, newest first (from `ls --help` itself)
- `head -1` will only keep 1 line at the top of anything

Answer (score 0):

Use `ls -lUt` or `ls -lUtr`, as you wish. You can take a look at the `ls` command documentation typing `man ls` on a terminal.